# Can anyone please explain the following c code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can anyone please tell me what the following c code means?

I would like to know why the variable `mesg` which is declared as `struct` again given a pointer at the end.

```
struct mesg 
 { 
 long type; 
 char mtext[MAX]; 
 } *mesg;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mesg` in `*mesg` is a pointer to a variable of type `struct mesg`.

For example,

```
struct mesg 
 { 
 long type; 
 char mtext[MAX]; 
 } abc;
```

here, `abc` denotes a variable of type `struct mesg`.

Simmilarly,

```
struct mesg 
 { 
 long type; 
 char mtext[MAX]; 
 } *mesg;
```

`mesg` in `*mesg` denotes a pointer to a variable of type `struct mesg`.

Maybe it'll be easier for you if you just use some other name as the variable name, like

```
struct mesg 
 { 
 long type; 
 char mtext[MAX]; 
 } *m;
```

Here, `m` is a pointer to a variable of type `struct mesg`.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to `struct mesg *mesg`, where `mesg` is a pointer variable of the type `struct mesg`.